# Chrome opens wrong application on Linux even after deleting ~/.config/google-chrome

Tags: linux, java, chrome

I recently upgraded from Fedora 23 to Fedora 27 which involved installing a new version of Chrome. I then discovered that Java was a pain to start, and in the course of experimenting I ended up telling Firefox and Chrome to open .jnlp extensions with Firefox.

Eventually I found the javaws binary and was able to tell Firefox to stop recursively opening itself and to launch /usr/java/latest/bin/javaws %U

However, Chrome still launches Firefox for every .jnlp extension (OK, it works with Firefox, but it's messy), but I've been unable to find a way to tell Chrome to use javaws instead. I've done a "egrep -ri 'jnlp|firefox' ~/.config/google-chrome" and deleted several files to no avail. I even deleted the entire ~/.config/google-chrome directory. However Chrome still launches Firefox for every .jnlp extension.

I've searched the web and everything talks about setting the default application for Windoze, but I'm running a proper OS. I even created a /usr/share/applications/javaws.desktop on that basis, but Chrome still insists on launching Firefox for .jnlp extensions.

How do I get rid of this setting and even better how do I get it to use javawa instead?

```
Lenovo Thinkpad T510
Linux 4.16.7-200.fc27.x86_64 x86_64

Google Chrome   66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)
Revision    a10b9cedb40738cb152f8148ddab4891df876959-refs/branch-heads/3359@{#828}
JavaScript  V8 6.6.346.32
Flash   24.0.0.189 internal-not-yet-present
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36
Command Line    /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end
Executable Path /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome

$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_171"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b10, mixed mode)
```

TIA Ken.

Answer (score 0):

After doing an strace of Chrome I finally found the config file it was reading and it wasn't in ~/.config/google-chrome

It's in ~/.config/mimeapps.list

```
application/x-java-jnlp-file=javaws.desktop;
```

There has to be a corresponding file /usr/share/applications/javaws.desktop with the details of how to execute javaws